# call a getter method from PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I call getter method into a sql query like this:

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed='$Object->getter()";
```

it is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.string.php) the string would be possible like so:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed='{$Object->getter()}'";
```

Consider using prepared statements so that your fields are always escpaed accordingly. See http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Using PDO it could look like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: what do you mean with getter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed='".$Object->getter()."'";
```

Your method is not calling as its treating the method call as `string` and not executing it, I just added method call outside the string so that it will execute `$Object->getter()` and used string concatenation i.e `.` to join the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this if you quoted your queries inside the single quotes

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed="'.$Object->getter().'"';
```

And you can use like this if you quoted your query in double quotes

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE filed='{$Object->getter()}'";
```

**Note:** inside the double quotes your php varibales are accessible

Comment: The second variant you provided is just correct for simple statements. See http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2357e8dbac7423deac4f502086ba5428b7feae5d